# Entity Framework for Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I am trying to create Repository , Entity framework for Portable Class Library , when ever I try to Nuget EntityFramework

it is Failed to add reference to 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

Any Idea to resolve this for EF

Compatible EF package for Portable Library

Comment: there is an issue in nuget related to this http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2978

Comment: What is the compatible package for Entity Framework in Portable Library

Comment: I have no problems with 6.1.0.  Be explicit about what targets you selected when you created your PCL project.

Comment: Windows 8, .Net 4.5 , SL5 , Windows Phone 8 are targets but failing while loading as stated above

Comment: I had the same error with a normal class library. A machine restart cleared it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF7 has PCL , so if any one planning to use PCL can use early version of EF7 or VS2014

Comment: Can you edit your answer to cite a source that "EF7 has PCL"?

Comment: But which NuGet Package needs to be installed? 
I am trying to use EntityFramework.SQLite (Beta6), but it won't install in PCL Library targeting Windows8/.Net4.5

Answer (score 4):

You can use fluent Api, don't use data annotations and attributes in the model class.

Example: for defining a primary key; instead of using `[Key]` tag, use:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasKey<int>(s => s.ID);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Visual Studio Update 2 you could create a PCL project that targets .Net 4 or .Net 4.5 and Windows 8, which would allow you to install the EntityFramework nuget package. After this update you cannot target Windows 8 without Windows Phone 8.1 being automatically targeted.

This auto targeting of Windows Phone seems to prevent adding EF package to PCL that targets Windows 8.