# Mapping Private Property in a Portable Class Library (Entity Framework 6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, portable-class-library

`private double _intrinsicValue {  get; set; }`

I'm attempting to use Entity Framework 6 to map a private property to a database table. I'm following the Code First pattern.

According to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/828444/Property-Mapping-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First), the prescribed way to do this is through an inner class that inherits from [`EntityTypeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg696117%28v=VS.113%29.aspx). Seems reasonable. Here's their example with my own comment placing the problem:

```
public class Payment
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }

    private DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    // Namespace for EntityTypeConfiguration inaccessible in Portable Class Library (comment my own)
    public class PaymentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Payment> 
    {
        public PaymentConfiguration()
        {
            Property(b => b.PaymentDate);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm attempting to do this in a Portable Class Library, in which I cannot reference the `System.Data` namespace necessary to the approach described in the aforementioned article.

Supposedly, Entity Framework 7 will support this, at least that's the tenuous conclusion from the **accepted** answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879578/entity-framework-for-portable-class-library). Note though that I do not consider this an answer to the question I'm about to ask, as I must work in the present.

Is this a no go? How can I use Entity Framework 6 to map a private property in a portable class library? Is there some sort of attribute based approach?

Comment: AFSIK this is a no-go for EF6.